# applying free shipping to in stock items only

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart, free-shipping

How can I create a shopping cart rules that apply free shipping to in stock items only?
in condition settings, I can not find stock item, is there one available to choose from?

Answer (score 2):

I think you should modify the conditions class to achieve your goal.

Take a look at the class `Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Product`. There is 3 new options related to the quote item (not product) was added:

```
/**
 * Add special attributes
 *
 * @param array $attributes
 * @return void
 */
protected function _addSpecialAttributes(array &$attributes)
{
    parent::_addSpecialAttributes($attributes);
    $attributes['quote_item_qty'] = __('Quantity in cart');
    $attributes['quote_item_price'] = __('Price in cart');
    $attributes['quote_item_row_total'] = __('Row total in cart');
}

/**
 * Validate Product Rule Condition
 *
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel $model
 * @return bool
 */
public function validate(\Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel $model)
{
    //@todo reimplement this method when is fixed MAGETWO-5713
    /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product */
    $product = $model->getProduct();
    if (!$product instanceof \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product) {
        $product = $this->productRepository->getById($model->getProductId());
    }

    $product->setQuoteItemQty(
        $model->getQty()
    )->setQuoteItemPrice(
        $model->getPrice() // possible bug: need to use $model->getBasePrice()
    )->setQuoteItemRowTotal(
        $model->getBaseRowTotal()
    );

    return parent::validate($product);
}
```

So you can rewrite this class and add the "in stock" condition. It is impossible to use only plugins, because one of the methods is protected :(